# SQL CASE, when column category = x group by category else don't group

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have this table:

```
date           client        category
-------------------------------------
2016-05-20     harrys        bar
2016-05-20     pitchers      bar
2016-05-20     eagle         sport
2016-05-21     claire        other
2016-05-21     maximus       other
2016-05-24     eagle         sport
2016-05-24     dolphin       sport
```

now the outcome is:

```
date           client        category
-------------------------------------
2016-05-20     harrys        bar       (two rows)
2016-05-20     eagle         sport
2016-05-21     claire        other     (two rows)
2016-05-24     eagle         sport     (two rows)
```

since I group bu the column category but I want the outcome to be:

```
date           client        category
-------------------------------------
2016-05-20     harrys        bar       (two rows)
2016-05-20     eagle         sport
2016-05-21     claire        other
2016-05-21     maximus       other
2016-05-24     eagle         sport
2016-05-24     dolphin       sport
```

So when the date and the category 'bar' match I want them to group. But I don’t want the category 'sport' nor 'other' to group when the date match.

I’ve tried locked in to `CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE`..etc. but I just don’t know how to write the sql statment.

I tried something like

```
SELECT *
FROM events
GROUP BY
CASE
    WHEN category = "bar" THEN category ELSE ""
END
```

which give me:

```
date           client        category
-------------------------------------
2016-05-20     harrys        bar
2016-05-20     eagle         sport
```

I also tried

```
WHEN category = "bar" THEN date, category ELSE ""
```

but it didn't work at all..

as you can see I have no idea how to use `CASE`… so any suggestions?

I've tried to read so many questions here at stackoverflow and also the manual for SQL statments etc. etc. I just don't understand how to use it.

Comment: **`MySQL` <> `Microsoft SQL Server`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT category, date, client
FROM events
WHERE category <> 'bar'
UNION ALL
SELECT category, date, MIN(client) AS client
FROM events
WHERE category = 'bar'
GROUP BY category, date;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/PYJ55429)**</kbd>

Comment: This works but I need to inner join too, and I don't think I'm doing it right, should I make another question or could you help me?

Comment: @Pixeldoris Please ask new question with real data and prepare http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I've created a new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324082/mysql-inner-join-together-with-union-all