# mySQL INNER JOIN together with UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, inner-join, union-all

I have a table with rows that's grouped if the date and the category 'bar' matches, now I need to `INNER JOIN` these with another table and use a `WHERE answer = '2'` from that table, but I don't know how to do that.

```
SELECT category, date, client
FROM sbs_events
WHERE category <> 'bar'
UNION ALL
SELECT category, date, MIN(client) AS client
FROM sbs_events
WHERE category = 'bar'
GROUP BY category, date
```

I've made a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb069/3)

The thing I need to add to the fiddle is

```
INNER JOIN sbs_userEvents
ON sbs_events.id = sbs_userEvents.event_id
WHERE answer = 2
AND user_id = 1
```

But since I already have a `WHERE category = 'bar'` I don't know how to add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT category, date, client
FROM sbs_events
INNER JOIN sbs_userEvents ON sbs_events.id = sbs_userEvents.event_id
WHERE category <> 'bar' AND answer = 2 AND user_id = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT category, date, MIN(client) AS client
FROM sbs_events
INNER JOIN sbs_userEvents ON sbs_events.id = sbs_userEvents.event_id
WHERE category = 'bar' AND answer = 2 AND user_id = 1
GROUP BY category, date
```